Unit-invariant treatments in panel data
Beginner with a beginner question about two-way fixed effects. I'm using R, if that's relevant.
Like the user in this question, I'm interested in estimating how time-varying (but unit-invariant) macro conditions affect firm sentiment; in my case, at the sector-level. However, my question is a little different. This answer may also partially address my question, although I found both the question and answer confusing.
In my case, I have data on: (1) ID of individual firms, (2) sector to which each of the firms belongs, (3) date (YYYY-MM-DD), (4) macro conditions, (5) firm sentiment, and (6) the topic to which the sentiment refers.

The "treatment" [macro conditions] and response [sentiment] are both continuous and range negative to positive.
Sector, topic, and firm are categorical.

First, I care about how the sign and also how the magnitude of the treatment affects responses. Second, observing differences in how certain sectors react is also key, which to me implies an interaction term. I imagine the relationship I want to estimate is something like:
$$ Sentiment_{ijt} = Macro_{jt} + Sector_i + Macro_{jt} * Sector_i $$
where $i$ is firm, $j$ is topic, and $t$ is a yearly aggregation. Usually, I see people include firm and year as fixed effects. But I'm skeptical a textbook approach would work here:

First, since each firm can only be assigned to one sector, and this doesn't vary over time, $Sector$ should be perfectly collinear with a firm FE.
Second, the whole point for me is to estimate differences in how different firms respond, so I don't think I want to include a firm FE.

I imagine I could use topic FE instead of firm FE. But I've never seen it done; units (in my experience) are usually spatial or entity-based.  So conceptually I have a hard time understanding what the unit of analysis (topic-years?) would even represent or if it's consistent with my actual research question.
I have also read that there are 3WFE solutions that could account for all the subscripts on $Y$, but I feel like this might be the wrong direction given my goal of observing sector-level differences (and how the subscripts on my predictors don't match the subscripts on $Y$).
Is modeling $Sentiment_{ijt}$ as an interaction between $Macro_{jt} * Sector_i$ with topic ($i$) / year ($t$) 2WFE a legitimate approach, given my research question? Or should my data be restructured in order to reduce the number of dimensions over which $Sentiment$ can vary?
